# Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-shared-drive

Scenario: I have to get a file from GCP shared google drive and put it in another folder on same shared drive.

Line of code:

> `files = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()`

This throws error in python

```
Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Apart from this I cannot see any error trace or any reason for this code break.
I try to get file of type either PDF or Google Doc from shared drive.

Note: I have used following libs:

```
google-api-core==1.22.0
google-api-python-client==1.12.5
google-auth==1.19.2
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
google-crc32c==0.1.0
google-resumable-media==0.7.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
httplib2==0.18.1
```

Comment: What is the file you're trying to get?

Comment: Do you have more information about the error?